# IntelliJ theme plugin fails to build (fatal error trying to buildSearchableOptions)

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, build.gradle, intellij-plugin

As a maintainer of the theme plugin [Cute Pink Light Theme](https://github.com/openmindculture/intellij-cute-pink-light-theme) for IntelliJ, I want to build releases for updated IntelliJ versions without getting any compilation errors or run-time errors.

Currently I get either a fatal build time error, or, using a workaround to skip building `searchableOptions`, a non-critical run-time error every time an IDE starts using the theme, although my plugin is only a theme and contains no plugin options anyway.

The theme has been built upon a fork of [JetBrains official plugin template repository](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-platform-plugin-template) in May 2021 and it used to work without errors with earlier IntelliJ versions (both build IDE version and target IDE versions).

Since target version 2022.1, building the project failed with the error `package com.apple.eawt.event not in java.desktop` when running verifications after building the project using the IDE's build menu. I tried to fix the errors by updating my code manually , integrating changes from the boilerplate repository and updates of the library dependencies, to make new builds for newer IntelliJ versions, using IntelliJ Ultimate as a build environment. I also bought the paid Ultimate version to ensure the problem is not caused by limitations of the free trial version.

I also included the workaround from [IDEA-210683](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210683) adding to tasks in `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
getByName<JavaExec>("buildSearchableOptions") {
    jvmArgs(
        "--illegal-access=deny",
        "--add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.desktop/sun.font=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.desktop/com.apple.eawt.event=ALL-UNNAMED"
    )
}
```

I also set VM options `--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --illegal-access=deny` to *Run Verifications* task as a workaround for [IDEA-210683 Illegal reflective access in IJ codebase](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210683) and in *general Java / Kotlin options*  in my IDE settings.

I also upgraded the Gradle IntelliJ Plugin to 1.6.0 as suggested in [IDEA-292389](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-292389).

After applying all mentioned updates and workarounds, [clearing IntelliJ cache folders](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003086459-kotlin-gradle-dsl-type-mismatch-expected-java-lang-string-but-inferred-type-is-kotlin-string), clearing gradle cache (`~/.gradle/caches/*`), rebuilding the project and running verifications, I still got the fatal build-time error `Execution failed for task ':buildSearchableOptions'.`

```
> Process 'command '/home/ingo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains/jbre/jbr_jcef-11_0_14_1-linux-x64-b2043.25/extracted/jbr/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':buildSearchableOptions'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:333)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:320)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:313)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:299)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:143)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:227)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:218)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/ingo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains/jbre/jbr_jcef-11_0_14_1-linux-x64-b2043.25/extracted/jbr/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:414)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.exec(JavaExec.java:165)
    at org.jetbrains.intellij.tasks.RunIdeBase.exec(RunIdeBase.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.intellij.tasks.BuildSearchableOptionsTask.exec(BuildSearchableOptionsTask.kt:22)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:171)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:60)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:180)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:144)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:333)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:320)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:313)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:299)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:143)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:227)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:218)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
```

As a final (succesful) workaround to produce a build artifact, I used the command line to build, excluding the subtask to build searchableOptions:

`./gradlew buildPlugin --exclude-task buildSearchableOptions`

The workaround produces a plugin file, that passes the verification when uploaded to JetBrains marketplace. But each time I start PhpStorm using a plugin version built with the workaround, I get an "IDE error" when starting my IDE.

Run-time error: "IDE Error"

Details:

```
Cannot create listener
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Cannot create listener com.github.openmindculture.intellijcutepinklighttheme.listeners.MyProjectManagerListener [Plugin: com.github.openmindculture.intellijcutepinklighttheme]
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.createListener(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:920)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.CompositeMessageBus.subscribeLazyListeners(CompositeMessageBus.java:177)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.CompositeMessageBus.doComputeSubscribers(CompositeMessageBus.java:147)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.computeSubscribers(MessageBusImpl.java:349)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.CompositeMessageBus.computeSubscribers(CompositeMessageBus.java:141)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.CompositeMessageBus$ToDirectChildrenMessagePublisher.lambda$publish$0(CompositeMessageBus.java:103)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.CompositeMessageBus$ToDirectChildrenMessagePublisher.publish(CompositeMessageBus.java:103)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$MessagePublisher.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:167)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.projectOpened(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImplKt$openProject$$inlined$executeInEdtWithProgress$1$1.run(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:605)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:608)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:683)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:639)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:607)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImplKt$openProject$$inlined$executeInEdtWithProgress$1.run(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:460)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:215)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:22)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:197)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:873)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$3.run(ApplicationImpl.java:511)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$1.run(LaterInvocator.java:96)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:69)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:42)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:898)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:439)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:803)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:438)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:106)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:604)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:436)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:873)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:484)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.openmindculture.intellijcutepinklighttheme.listeners.MyProjectManagerListener PluginClassLoader(plugin=PluginDescriptor(name=Cute Pink Light Theme, id=com.github.openmindculture.intellijcutepinklighttheme, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~/.local/share/JetBrains/PhpStorm2022.1/intellij-cute-pink-light-theme, version=0.3.0, package=null, isBundled=false), packagePrefix=null, instanceId=86, state=active)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImplKt.doLoadClass(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:1469)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImplKt.access$doLoadClass(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:1)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.createListener(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:917)
    ... 48 more
```

The theme still works as expected, and the error is not fatal, but it shows on every startup.

Due to the complex requirements, I am not able to provide a minimal code example, but here are possibly relevant settings:

`gradle.properties`:

```
platformType = IC
platformVersion = 2022.1
platformDownloadSources = true
platformPlugins =
javaVersion = 11
gradleVersion = 7.4.2
kotlin.stdlib.default.dependency = false
org.gradle.warning.mode=all

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 11
    targetCompatibility = 11
}

compilerArgs.addAll(
    listOf(
        "--enable-preview",
        "-Xlint:all",
        "-parameters",
        "--add-opens",
        "java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED"
        // "-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions",
    )
)
```

Steps to reproduce:

- checkout the [repository](https://github.com/openmindculture/intellij-cute-pink-light-theme)
- open in IntelliJ Ultimate 2022.2 (build 222.2270.31)

To reproduce the fatal build-time error:

- `Build` the project from IntelliJ `Build` menu.
- `Run Verifications` from IntelliJ `Build` menu.

To reproduce the run-time error:

- `Build` the project from IntelliJ `Build` menu.
- run shell command: `./gradlew buildPlugin --exclude-task buildSearchableOptions`
- Open an IntelliJ IDEA (like PhpStorm), go to Settings -> Plugins -> Gear Icon -> install plugin from disk and add the zip file found in `build/distributions`.

Comment: I'd recommend you raise this issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development  so that IDEA Core team could take a look at it

Comment: Thanks @EgorKlepikov, I will do as well. But after my recent experience with YouTrack (and no option to reopen other peoples' issues that are marked as "fixed") I thought it might raise more attention here. Sorry.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov done: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/4158954

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the fatal errors, obsolete boilerplate code from the JetBrains plugin template code must be removed. [According to JetBrains support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/6575352387986/comments/6593887333522), it does not belong in a plugin that is only a theme, and should have been removed from the start:

#### Remove Obsolete Plugin Template Code

All files in folder `src/main/kotlin` and sub-folders are obsolete for a theme and must be deleted.

The following code must be removed from `src/main/resources/META-INF/plugin.xml`:

```xml
<!-- inside <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij"> -->
  <applicationService serviceImplementation="com.github.openmindculture.intellijcutepinklighttheme.services.MyApplicationService"/>
  <projectService serviceImplementation="com.github.openmindculture.intellijcutepinklighttheme.services.MyProjectService"/>

<!-- remove unused application listener -->
  <applicationListeners>
    <listener class="com.github.openmindculture.intellijcutepinklighttheme.listeners.MyProjectManagerListener" topic="com.intellij.openapi.project.ProjectManagerListener"/>
  </applicationListeners>
```

#### Disable buildSearchableOptions using Task Options

The `buildSearchableOptions` task should be disabled, as a theme does not need plugin options anyway. The proper way to disable the task is to define  the `task` as `enabled = false`. This also obsoletes the workaround for `buildSearchableOptions` taken from [IDEA-210683](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210683/Illegal-reflective-access-in-IJ-codebase#focus=Comments-27-4620700.0-0) which must be removed.

Add to `build.gradle.kts`:

```
tasks {
    buildSearchableOptions {
        enabled = false
    }
```

#### Remove Obsolete Workaround Task

Remove from `build.gradle.kts`:

```
getByName<JavaExec>("buildSearchableOptions") {
  jvmArgs(
    "--illegal-access=deny",
    "--add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED",
    "--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED",
    "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED",
    "--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED",
    "--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED",
    "--add-opens=java.desktop/sun.font=ALL-UNNAMED",
    "--add-opens=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED",
    "--add-opens=java.desktop/com.apple.eawt.event=ALL-UNNAMED"
  )
}
```

After fixing the issues and clearing previous build artifacts, I was able to build the theme plugin without errors again, but plugin verification failed after uploading to the marketplace.

Update: I have received further instruction on removing obsolete code, and I was also asked to prevent cross-posting, so please refer to the [issue 6575352387986 in JetBrains' official support channel](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/6575352387986-IntelliJ-theme-plugin-fails-to-build-fatal-error-trying-to-buildSearchableOptions-?page=1#community_comment_6700392030994) for any further details.

You can also use my updated, minimal [source code (tag 0.4.4 or newser)](https://github.com/openmindculture/intellij-cute-pink-light-theme/releases/tag/0.4.4) as an example to build an IntelliJ theme without unnecessary Java and Kotlin dependencies.

Comment: The fixed code builds when targeted for current stable 2022.1 (221) IDEs. It still fails when using a 2022.2 EAP version to build for 2022.2 (222) target, but that would be another issue.

Comment: Despite building a plugin artifact that works without errors on my local machine, the release failed the official plugin verification, so I will have to update my answer when I have found out what else has gone wrong.